# SSH and Docker Exec together are not accepting multiple commands

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ssh, command-line

I need to create a shell script that connects to a remote machine using SSH and then runs some commands inside a docker container that is running on that machine.

I want the below command to work. But it only executes first command in the container.

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 docker exec my-container bash -c command1 && command2 && command3
```

So far the best solution I could come up with is this:

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 "docker exec my-container bash -c 'command1 && command2 && command3'"
```

But it only works with some commands. I can run commands like mkdir echo but I couldn't use curl with it.

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 "docker exec my-container bash -c 'curl --verbose --stderr stderr -X GET "http://2.2.2.2:5000/file/download" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $1" > curl_out
```

I somehow need to make the curl command work. It succesfully expands $1 as the authorization token but curl command does not see use the headers. I couldn't get it to work.

Is there a better way of constructing this kind of nested command pipe. I have tried like 50 different combinations of quotes, different variables, trying to write the echo inside a shell script inside the container and then running it. Each solution fails upon trying to use complex commands with multiple options / arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 docker exec my-container \
  bash -c command1 && command2 && command3
```

You are just creating a local shell pipeline. That's the same thing as if you were to run:

```
date && command2 && command3
```

Your shell doesn't magically know that you intended to run those second two commands on the remote host. If you want to pass that entire shell pipeline to the remote host, you need to quote it.

You might be tempted to do something like this:

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 docker exec my-container \
  bash -c "command1 && command2 && command3"
```

But that still won't work as intended: in this case, you are running the command `docker exec my-container bash -c command1 && command2 && command3` on the remote host. That is, only `command1` is being run inside the container. You need another level of quoting:

```
ssh -i key user@1.1.1.1 docker exec my-container \
  'bash -c "command1 && command2 && command3"'
```